# How to add member function of template class only on specific types using type_traits | C++

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
        template <std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed_v<T>, bool> = true>
        constexpr value_type determinant()
        {
            
        }
}
```

I wanna determinant function is instantiated only when type `T` is signed type
so I try this codes, but when type `T` is unsigned compiler still try instantiate determinant function.

I don't wanna specialize template function about each signed type `T`.
I want to use `std::is_signed_v` type traits to simplify codes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With SFINAE you can enable/disable a method of a class when the condition tested is related to a template parameter of the method itself. Doesn't works testing a template parameter of the class.

You can solve the problem passing through a method template parameter that is defaulted with the type of the class/struct template parameter.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct foo
 {
   template <typename U = T,
             std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed_v<U>, bool> = true>
   constexpr std::size_t bar ()
    { return sizeof(T); }
 };

int main() 
 {
   foo<signed int>   fs;
   foo<unsigned int> fu;

   fs.bar(); // compile
   //fu.bar(); // compilation error
 }
```

The problem of this solution is that you can "hijack" it explicating a template parameter

```
fu.bar(); // compilation error
fu.bar<int>(); // compile
```

To avoid the hijacking risk, you can (other solutions are possible but this is my preferred) add a non-type variadic template parameter before `U`

```
// .......VVVVVVVV  add this to avoid the hijacking problem
template <int ...,
          typename U = T,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed_v<U>, bool> = true>
constexpr std::size_t bar ()
 { return sizeof(T); }

// ...

fu.bar(); // compilation error
fu.bar<int>(); // compilation error
fu.bar<1, 2, 3, int>(); // compilation error
```

Comment: Ha, that anti-hijacking technique is cool. Will keep that in mind. Only the error message is a bit mediocre :)

Comment: @florestan - Yes, is very cool. Unfortunately I don't remember who suggested it to me.

Comment: I'd be interested in the other techniques. Perhaps I could open a question?

Comment: @florestan - There is another obvious technique: add a `std::is_same_v<T, U>` condition in the test.

Comment: Which is not as cool as the other one, but if you put it into a static_assert you'll probably get a better error message. Why do you prefer the other one?

Comment: can you let me know why i can't use T at template member function of template class

Comment: @hour30000 - You can use `T` in the method. But you can't use to (directly) SFINAE enable/disable the method. I don't exactly what C++ rule is, but is a C++ rule.

Comment: @florestan - the `static_assert()` solution is a good one but isn't a SFINAE one. I mean... with `static_assert()` you can get an hard error if you call the method in the wrong class. With SFINAE you have a soft error so you can develop multiple alternative methods: one for signed types, one for unsigned type, in this case. You can't develop alternative methods using `static_assert()`.

Comment: sure, but the `static_assert(std::is_same_v<U,T>)` would be within the sfinaed function template, so it wouldn't trigger except if the user would hijack the first template parameter. In this case it *should* fail, IMHO.

Comment: @florestan - Yes, combining SFINAE and `static_assert()` could be a third way to avoid hijacking.